# Why is the throw hook not being called in old SpiderMonkey JSDBGAPI?

Tags: c++, spidermonkey

I'm running SpiderMonkey 31. Whenever a throw an error, the throw handler doesn't get called even when JS_SetThrowHook method has been called. Is there a specific configuration for this? I checked the new script hook and the destroy hook and they are working.

Comment: @FUZxxl C++ users also use spidermonkey.

Comment: That's not a reason to tag this as C++. Are you programming in C or are you programming in C++? That's the only relevant thing. It would help if you could make a minimal self-contained example of your problem.

Comment: I'm programming in C++.